# Why does jQuery considers 'Enter' Keypress event as Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider a following code:

```
$(document.body).click(function(e) {
console.log(e.clientX);
});
```

This event is supposed to fire when ever I make a click.  But I have a search bar in my application.  When ever I type something in the search bar and press enter it is calling the click event.  Is that a bug in jQuery or I am missing any JS concept.

To replicate this issue, go to www.ebay.in then open firebug in FF then run the above script in console.

1. Then click anywhere you should get the X coordinate.
2. Place the cursor in the search bar then press enter having 'Persist' on on the
   console.  You will see 0

Any clarification would be really helpful.

Comment: wherever you click on page it is clicked in page body its obvious

Comment: This isn't a jQuery thing, you'd see similar results binding a click handler with plain JS.

Comment: Answers below should answer your question, but if you want a work-around, simply check what keyCode was set in e.keyCode, if thats 13 (which is an Enter), don't execute your function. Maybe you should check wether e.keyCode is set full stop, because it doesn't seem to be set in the click event.

Comment: @Milanzor The strange thing is I did not get 13 for e.keyCode for click event.  I got 1. Because of that I made a workarround like e.clientX == 0 for enter key press event hope it helps others.

Comment: @DilipRajkumar Strange, I didn't seem to get any keyCode from the click, perhaps the jQuery version is different and they changed it. If you use your work-around and you would click on clientX 0, your function will not fire, which could mean you miss out on a click. Seeing as clientX is the complete left side of your screen, it won't suprise me if users click there.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree @Milanzor I too thought about that, for now the probability for breaking that feature is less so I left it live like that.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing Enter inside an input field simulates a click on the first submittable button on the form. This is standard and desired behaviour, but when blindly accepting `click` events it may produce an otherwise unexpected click.

Comment: This actually seems more like a hack to get "returned" fields to submit a form. But still, I guess it makes it easier to tie events to a "submit" of the form. It's always interesting to see how software is designed to work, and what methods are used to solve problems.

Comment: Thank you @niet.. So it is a default behavior of browser, I suffered a lot without knowing this funda... I was looking all over the platform for a click event trigger..:)  Thanks I can accept answer only after 7 mins it seams.. I will accept the answer in 7 mins..